# Jboss doesn't deploy war, JBAS011006

Tags: jboss7.x

I need your help!

I'm trying to deploy my WAR to Jboss Application Server 7.1 and I can't achieve it. 
I deploy it through web console and it freeze during deploying without any errors. 
That's my server.log (http://rghost.ru/41253318)

Thanks!

```
12:08:26,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:08:26,708 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 1904ms - Started 161 of 240 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
12:08:33,960 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014901: Content removed from location C:\JBoss\standalone\data\content\bc\e2b74994970823aa57cc8a48392df844788444\content
12:08:41,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\JBoss\standalone\data\content\bc\e2b74994970823aa57cc8a48392df844788444\content
12:09:00,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "USCINS_1.1.5.war"
12:09:02,978 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry hk2-core.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api-3.1.8.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,980 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry config.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api-3.1.8.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,981 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry auto-depends.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api-3.1.8.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,983 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry asm-all-repackaged.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api-3.1.8.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry bean-validator.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/ha-api-3.1.8.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,986 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,989 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,991 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,995 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,997 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,998 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxws-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:02,999 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jsr181-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,001 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry javax.annotation.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,002 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry saaj-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,004 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry saaj-impl.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,005 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry stax2-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,006 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry woodstox-core-asl.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,008 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,009 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,011 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry stax-ex.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,012 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry streambuffer.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,013 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry stax-utils.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,015 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry policy.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,016 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry gmbal-api-only.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,017 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry management-api.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,019 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxws-rt.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,020 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-xjc.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.2.6.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,026 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry relaxngDatatype.jar in "/c:/JBoss/bin/content/USCINS_1.1.5.war/WEB-INF/lib/xsdlib-20060615.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:09:03,618 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSAsyncListener$1 due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSAsyncListener$1
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to bundle jaxws & jaxb with your application as they are already part of JDK/App server.

remove jaxws*, jaxb* from your war and it should probably work or at least give you some other error.

if it still does not work, can you post output of

```
jar tf <name-of-you-war>
```

that will show us the structure of your war.