# Apache camel war deployment JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-eap-6

Iam trying to deploy a sample camel war application created using maven archetype camel-archetype-web:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes/camel-archetype-web/2.10.0.redhat-60092

Iam getting below info and warning in logs ,the camel application is not running.

The application is placed in below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7junC5UmfFgNlFJVnFtOENtd2s/view?usp=sharing

Server log:

```
10:11:49,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
10:11:51,324 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Temp/FSW/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/content/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:11:51,340 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Temp/FSW/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/content/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:11:51,355 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/Temp/FSW/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/content/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:11:51,371 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /C:/Temp/FSW/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/content/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:11:51,527 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 110) JBAS018210: Register web context: /sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
10:11:51,543 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 110) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
10:11:51,558 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 110) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
10:11:52,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" with deployment "sampleapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
```

Any Help appreciated.

Comment: `jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar` has explicit `Class-Path` manifest headers. This is only warning, but when you decided to use application server, I'd rely on jaxb-impl provided by server itself.

Comment: Yes i understood it by refering the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154521/jboss-doesnt-deploy-war-jbas011006  ,The camel application is not getting started.is it because of the info No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath?

Comment: You can deploy Camel as a dependency in an EAP 6.1 application-- but that's not the best way!
The best way is to upgrade to EAP 6.4, where you can use the Fuse/EAP bits.  (This is the productized version of Wildfly-Camel).  Much easier, with lots of free functionality.)

Comment: Hi Rick,I forgot to mention Iam using fuse service works 6.0.it already has all the camel related dependencies..

Comment: "No Spring WebApplicationInitializer" is not even a WARN it's just info that no class implementing org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer was detected